# DFS and BFS trees related to undirected connected simple graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given an undirected connected simple graph G, let Td be a DFS tree and Tb be a BFS tree of G starting at some fixed vertex.

If Tb and Td are identical then G is an acyclic graph. Is this always true?

I worked on the following example :

let Td and Tb be :

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(B,D)
(B,E)
(C,F)
(C,G)
```

and then graph could be :

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(B,D)
(B,E)
(C,F)
(C,G)
(C,A)
```

Am i thinking in the right direction? Because the answer given for this problem is true which according to me should be false.

Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @Paulw11 : I didn't know that it is off-topic question. Can you please tell me where should I post this question or see my edited post with the example that I have referred?

Comment: @Paulw11 : can you please see the question and reply.